# Terraform Azure Automation install SqlServer module

Tags: terraform, azure-powershell

I'm trying to install the module SqlServer into my automation account.
This is the terraform code.

```
resource "azurerm_automation_module" "mod_sqlserver" {
  name                    = "xSqlServer"
  resource_group_name     = module.aut_resourcegroup.rg.name
  automation_account_name = azurerm_automation_account.aut.name

  module_link {
    uri = "https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.1.18256"
  }
}
```

But the URL of the package is wrong. I can't find the right URL.
I have tried several combinations, even with the .nupkg extension at the back, but no good so far.

Anybody has a idea how to code this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
uri = "https://devopsgallerystorage.blob.core.windows.net/packages/sqlserver.21.1.18256.nupkg"
```

Instead of

```
uri = "https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/SqlServer/21.1.18256"
```

As the uri you are using takes you to the powershell gallery page but uri that I have mentioned it downloads the package from the devops gallery.